# MySQL Query to return rows that contain whitespace

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to run a query on a MySQL database table to return all the rows where the column data has white space. e.g.:

**Usernames**
andy davies
peter
geoff smith
steve
bob paul

The query would only return 'andy davies', 'geoff smith', 'bob paul' and ignore 'peter' and 'steve'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
   ...
  WHERE username LIKE '% %'
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, even though there were a couple of rows containing a space.

Answer (score 9):

INSTR() returns the position of the specified substring in the given string. Use it in the WHERE conditional.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE INSTR(`username`, ' ') > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

An idea:

```
SELECT names FROM tbl_name WHERE names LIKE "% %";
```

Answer (score 1):

This version checks for all white space including tabs and new lines (it assumes the column is `username`):

```sql
SELECT
  username,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(username, ' ', ''), '\t', ''), '\n', '') AS username_clean
FROM [your_table]
HAVING username <> username_clean;
```

Comment: This helped me. Thanks!