# SQL LIKE wildcard space character

Tags: mysql, sql

let's say I have a string in which the words are separated by 1 or more spaces and I want to use that string in and SQL LIKE condition. How do I make my SQL and tell it to match 1 or more blank space character in my string? Is there an SQL wildcard that I can use to do that?

Let me know

Comment: Hum, I don't know if there is a solution but anyway, using like or wildcard in sql queries is a bad practice because it can be very slow. Prefer using an index engine like Lucene to do such a query

Comment: Please post your table structure and the query you have tried so far.

Comment: `LIKE '% %'` would match any string that contains 1 or more spaces... but what do you want to do with that match?  Just return the record? Convert it to a single space?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Query to return rows that contain whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969315/mysql-query-to-return-rows-that-contain-whitespace)

Answer (score 9):

If you're just looking to get anything with atleast one blank / whitespace then you can do something like the following `WHERE myField LIKE '% %'`

Answer (score 7):

If your dialect allows it, use SIMILAR TO, which allows for more flexible matching, including the normal regular expression quantifiers '?', '*' and '+', with grouping indicated by '()'

```
where entry SIMILAR TO 'hello +there'
```

will match `'hello there'` with any number of spaces between the two words.

I guess in MySQL this is

```
where entry RLIKE 'hello +there'
```

Comment: nice one for mysql.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is late, but I never found a solution to this in relation to a `LIKE` question.

There is no way to do what you're wanting within a `SQL LIKE`. What you would have to do is use `REGEXP` and `[[:space:]]` inside your expression.

So to find one or more spaces between two words..

```
WHERE col REGEXP 'firstword[[:space:]]+secondword'
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to match for one or more space would be to use `[]`.
It's done like this.

```
LIKE '%[ ]%'
```

This will match one or more spaces.

Comment: As far as I can that only matches exactly 1 space in the same way `'% %'` does. i.e. `'Hello[ ]World'` won't match where there are two spaces between Hello and World.

Answer (score 3):

you can't do this using LIKE but what you can do, if you know this condition can exist in your data, is as you're inserting the data into the table, use regular expression matching to detect it up front and set a flag in a different column created for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I just **replace the whitespace chars with '%'**. Lets say I want to do a **LIKE query** on a string like this *'I want to query this string with a LIKE'*

```
@search_string = 'I want to query this string with a LIKE'
@search_string = ("%"+@search_string+"%").tr(" ", "%")
@my_query = MyTable.find(:all, :conditions => ['my_column LIKE ?', @search_string])
```

first I add the **'%'** to the **start and end** of string with

> ("%"+@search_string+"%")

and then replace other **remaining whitespace** chars with **'%'** like so

> .tr(" ", "%")

Comment: the issue about this, if that matches with "first second", it wont find "second first"

Answer (score 1):

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php

> The patterns that you can choose from are:
>
> % allows you to match any string of any length (including zero length)
>
> _ allows you to match on a single character

Answer (score 1):

I think that the question is not asking to match any spaces but to match two strings one a pattern and the other with wrong number of spaces because of typos.

In my case I have to check two fields from different tables one preloaded and the other filled typed by users so sometimes they don't respect 100% the pattern.

The solution was to use LIKE in the join

```
   Select table1.field
    from table1
    left join table2 on table1.field like('%' + replace(table2.field,' ','%')+'%')
```

Answer (score -4):

if the condition:

```
WHERE myField LIKE '%Hello world%'
```

doesn't work try

```
WHERE myField LIKE '%Hello%'
```

and

```
WHERE myField LIKE '%world%'
```

this approach is helpful in a few specific use cases, hope this helps.