# Jpa no result if select from column with white spaces

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, servlets, jpa

if "key" parameter contains white spaces(ex: "cat and dog") the query result is empty..Why?

```
Query q=em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Articolo a WHERE a.nome LIKE '%"+key+"%'");
```

but if key parameter cointains only "cat" or "and" or "dog" it works?

Comment: and your JPA implementation converts that JPQL into what SQL statement? That is what the log is for

Comment: the column 'nome' in mysql cointains white spaces

Comment: Are there any records in your table which match your filter?

Comment: yes there is a record in table Articolo with white spaces(ex: cat and dog)

Comment: But if in Workbench i do this query : select * from articolo where nome='cat and dog'; I havent any results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting any result executing below query in the database,

SELECT a FROM Articolo a WHERE a.nome LIKE '%"+key+"%'

'cat and dog' has two spaces probably that could be the reason it does not get. JPQL, HQL, JDBC works in same way of.

But, i suggest before we write jpql query we can check the query results in database.

Comment: i solved it ..'cat and dog' has three spaces ...yeessss ..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Consider use named parameters when you try to do that.

```
Query q=em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Articolo a WHERE a.nome LIKE :value);
q.setParameter("value", "%dog%");
```

Also read this [SQL LIKE wildcard space character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946219/sql-like-wildcard-space-character)